# How can I make a 3x3 grid box that contains 9 input textboxes without double border thickness?

Tags: html, css, border

I had make an `input` square contains 3 rows and 3 columns. But the intersected borders between each two input boxes have double thickness, because one of the borders is overlapped on the other border and this creates double border thickness. This case can be understanded easily by running the `html` below. How can I make the borders have only one line?

```css
.container{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 90px;
}
.box {
    color: darkgreen;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    color:gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
            <input class="box" type="text""><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by removing the border from only certain elements. The easiest way to do this is by using the `nth-child()` pseudo selector on the elements, which selects HTML elements based on the order of the children. The following code should work:

```
/* Add left and top border to all cells */
.box {
    border: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

/* Add right border to elements at the end of rows */
.box:nth-child(3n) {
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

/* Add bottom border to elements at the bottom */
.box:nth-child(n+7) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `outline` property, which adds a border into the margin of elements. Be sure to set the `border` property itself to 0, to avoid borders that are thicker than expected. The code will look like this:

```
.box {
    border: 0;
    outline: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: It is good but hard to generalize and takes so much code. In the above, @satinez's answer `outline` seems better to me. Thanks

Comment: I understand, I've updated the answer with a method that's easier to generalize, and with one that uses the `outline` property.

Answer (score 1):

u can try it with nth-child pseudo selector :)

Comment: I used `outline` in input box style and now the boxes have the same thickness on its outside. But it is a bit thick even the `outline` size is 1px. Is there any lower measurement than 1px? By the way I suggest you to update  your answer with the comment above to be acceptable.

Comment: Remember that input fields automatically have a border to them in most browsers. The `outline` property simply adds a border in the margin. So, set `border: 0;` to get the thinnest size you can get. You can't go below 1px :p